# Carima non-toxic resin?

Tags: resin, toxicity

I just discovered a resin from [Carima](https://carima.com/130) which says it's non-toxic. They have a link to a technical data sheet, but it leads to a page that requires me to request access, so I haven't read that yet. Has anyone tried this resin, or even heard reports on its quality and ease of use as resin? I really like the non-toxic idea, but it has to work well, too.